# how to remove 'Appendix' prefixes from Bookmarks while keeping in ToC and Appendices?

Tags: pdftex, appendices, bookmarks

In the test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect{\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}}}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\begin{appendices}
\section{Test.1}
\subsection{Test.1.1}
\section{Test.2}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

need to remove 'Appendix' prefixes from Bookmarks (mean leave Appendices names only), while keeping them in ToC and Appendices itself. How to do this?

Tried:

```
\renewcommand\appendixname{}
```

but in addition to Bookmarks it removes 'Appendix' from ToC and Appendices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\texorpdfstring` is you want something different in the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixname{\texorpdfstring{Appendix}{}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect{\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}}}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\begin{appendices}
\section{Test.1}
\subsection{Test.1.1}
\section{Test.2}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you. and thanks for understanding